# non blocking "Key pressed" test in C

Tags: c, keyboard

I'm looking for a pretty simple thing:

I want to test if a key was pressed. *any key*.
If not, the program should continue its business.
So it must be a "non blocking" call.

I guess this question is probably equivalent to checking if the keyboard buffer has anything into it.

I guess such a function must exist in C for that, but I can't quite find it yet. All standard functions I find are "blocking" type, waiting for a key to be pressed before answering.

Note - I'm planning to use it for a Windows console program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In windows you can use '_kbhit()' in conio.h
It is a non-standard function and may not be available on other platforms.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a bit old but here is some Linux code that works

```
kbhit.h:
#ifndef KBHIT_H__
  #define KBHIT_H__

  void  init_keyboard(void);
  void  close_keyboard(void);
  int   kbhit(void);
  int   readch(void); 

#endif 
  
kbhit.c:
#include "kbhit.h"
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>   // for read()

static struct termios initial_settings, new_settings;
static int peek_character = -1;

void init_keyboard(void)
{
    tcgetattr(0,&initial_settings);
    new_settings = initial_settings;
    new_settings.c_lflag &= ~ICANON;
    new_settings.c_lflag &= ~ECHO;
    new_settings.c_lflag &= ~ISIG;
    new_settings.c_cc[VMIN] = 1;
    new_settings.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;
    tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &new_settings);
}

void close_keyboard(void)
{
    tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &initial_settings);
}

int kbhit(void)
{
unsigned char ch;
int nread;

    if (peek_character != -1) return 1;
    new_settings.c_cc[VMIN]=0;
    tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &new_settings);
    nread = read(0,&ch,1);
    new_settings.c_cc[VMIN]=1;
    tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &new_settings);
    if(nread == 1) 
    {
        peek_character = ch;
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int readch(void)
{
char ch;

    if(peek_character != -1) 
    {
        ch = peek_character;
        peek_character = -1;
        return ch;
    }
    read(0,&ch,1);
    return ch;
}
main.c:
#include "kbhit.h"
#define Esc 27
int main(void)
{
 init_keyboard(); // for kbhit usage
 do {
   if(kbhit())
     {
      ch = tolower(readch());
      if(ch == Esc || ch == 'q') break;
      if(ch=='s') GetNewTimerValue(TIMER_1);
      if(ch=='f') GetNewTimerValue(TIMER_2);
      if(ch=='l') {rotateFields();}

     }
   usleep(330000);
  } while(1);

 close_keyboard();
return 0;     
}
```